# How to check dynamic text in espresso UI test

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, ui-testing

I need to perform simple test - text view matching.
It is simple thing with:

```
onView(withId(R.id.titleTextView)).check(matches(withText("Special Offer: First 3 Minutes Free")));
```

But this part "First 3 Minutes Free" randomly changes with "Get $1.99 for calls" after each activity start.

How can I verify both cases? Operator `||` is not allowed in Espresso...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Hamcrest `anyOf` inside `withText` method:

```
onView(withId(R.id.titleTextView)).check(matches(withText(anyOf(is("Special Offer: First 3 Minutes Free"),is("Special Offer: Get $1.99 for calls")))));
```